# How to Make values of Array Comma separated

Tags: php

What I need:

- number separated by (,) .

  ```
     like :  42166 ,42167 , 42168,42169 etc.
  ```

problem im facing :

- the  number is not  appended by(,).
- im using implode function.

Array Structure:

```
 Array
(
[id] => 42166
[Company_Website] => http://www.amphenol-highspeed.com/
[company_name] => Amphenol High Speed Interconnect
[city_name] => New York
[country_name] => USA
[comp_img] => 
 )

42166Array 
(
  [id] => 42167
[Company_Website] => http://www.clearfieldconnection.com/
[company_name] => Clearfield, Inc.
[city_name] => Plymouth
[country_name] => USA
[comp_img] => 
)
```

Php Code:

```
    foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {

    echo $company_id= implode(",",(array)$value['id']);
      }

       output im getting:  412664127741288 etc.
```

Comment: What PHP-version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
    $company_id[] = $value['id'];
}
$company_id = implode (',', $company_id);
```

Edit : Sorry that I misread your question at first time

Comment: i want in this manner like :  42166 ,42167 , 42168,42169 etc. you code output - 4,2,1,6, for 4126 .

Comment: @user3785613 Wow, did you edit your question or I totally misread it ? I was sure you asked for 4,3,2... ? Anyway, updated my answer, and gonna grab some coffee to wake me up

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=0;
$company_id = "";
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
    $company_id .= ($i==0)?$value['id']:','.$value['id'];
    $i++;
}
echo $company_id;
```

Comment: output: ,42166,42167,42169,42172, i just want 42166,42167,42169,42172

Comment: Weird, maybe change ($i==0) to ($i<1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `Id` values into comma separated then0 try by string manipulation and append comma (,) with each id value

```
$company_id = ""
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
    $company_id .= $value['id'].",";
}
echo rtrim($company_id, ",");
```